# bash error when comparing string with slash

Tags: bash

Why is it an error if string starts with a slash?

```
[[ "/a" -eq "a" ]]
-bash: [[: /a: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/a")
```

Seems a bit unexpected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is not `/` but use of `-eq` operator, which is used for integer equality in shell.

If you change `-eq` with `=` then error will not be there:

```
[[ "/a" = "a" ]] && date || pwd
```

Comment: That's not safe if the string may start with a dash.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler, could you elaborate with example?

Comment: @IndustryUser1942 Forget it, for some reason I had the impression this is a `[...]` expression. With `[[ ... ]]` there is no such problem.

Comment: '/' is interepreted as division operator, when -eq is in use.
`[[ "4/2" -eq 2 ]] && echo true || echo false` -> `true`